# Query three tables with inner join

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm working on a sql database with three tables.

PageIds
Links
Ranks

I want to query the database with a page name and find all links for the given page name, furthermore I want to get Links sorted by a Score.

The PageName used for the query either exists as PageA or as PageB, and if PageA then I want PageBs PageName and PageBs PageScore - and vice versa.

I know I have to use inner joins, but how should I handle 'or' in inner join and how do get PageId in PageIds, to query other table and then PageName in PageIds.

This what I have tried, but it take quite some time and then I will not get the opposite PageName

```
select * from PageIds 
inner join Links
on Links.PageAId = PageIds.PageId or Links.PageBId = PageIds.PageId
inner join Ranks 
on Ranks.PageId = Links.PageBId
where PageIds.PageName = @searchternm
```

**PageIds**

Get PageId for PageName matching @searchterm

```
+--------+----------+
| PageId | PageName |
+--------+----------+
|   1234 | NameA    |
|   4321 | NameB    |
|   3321 | NameC    |
+--------+----------+
```

**Links**

if previously found PageId = PageAId,
then get PageBId and PageName for PageBId,
else get PageAId and PageName for PageAId

```
+---------+---------+
| PageAId | PageBId |
+---------+---------+
|    1234 |    3321 |
|    4321 |    3321 |
|    1234 |    4321 |
+---------+---------+
```

**Ranks**

if previously found PageId = PageAId,
then get score for PageBId,
else get score for PageAId

```
+--------+-----------+
| PageId | PageScore |
+--------+-----------+
|   1234 |      1    |
|   3321 |      4    |
|   4321 |      2    |
+--------+-----------+
```

If input is NameB then the output should be:

```
PageName, Score

NodeC, 4
NodeA, 1
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm a little confused, with the test data in the question what will be the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly you'll want to join the PageIDs table twice, once as PageAIDs and once as PageBIDs.

Then have one query pick up pageA details where pageB matches, then union it with a reversed query for pageB details where pageA matches.

```
SELECT PageA.PageName, RanksA.Score FROM Links
INNER JOIN PageIDs [PageA] on Links.PageAID = PageA.PageID
INNER JOIN PageIDs [PageB] on Links.PageBID = PageB.PageID
INNER JOIN Ranks [RanksA] on Links.PageAID = RanksA.PageID
WHERE PageB.PageName = @PageName
UNION 
SELECT PageB.PageName, RanksB.Score FROM Links
INNER JOIN PageIDs [PageA] on Links.PageAID = PageA.PageID
INNER JOIN PageIDs [PageB] on Links.PageBID = PageB.PageID
INNER JOIN Ranks [RanksB] on Links.PageBID = RanksB.PageID
WHERE PageA.PageName = @PageName
```

Comment: I've just noticed the conditioning you want, I'll edit my response to include that shortly.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Not quit sure on your use of tables and columns  in that query, but I got it to work with union keyword. That is still a lot of joins and each query takes about 5 sec. Isn't there any way to optimize this?

Comment: Is page ID a primary key on the page Id and score tables? If not I'd start any optimisation there. SQL optimisation is a tough subject though much of which depends on the table structure.

Comment: No not in in Links, because it contains two PageId per row. Should I change that?